# Splitting TextBlob sentiment analysis results into two separate columns - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, textblob

```
from textblob import TextBlob

def sentiment_calc(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).sentiment
    except:
        return None

test_df['sentiment score'] = test_df['text'].apply(sentiment_calc)
test_df
```

I recently ran a code on my dataset to implement sentiment analysis using the TextBlob package. After running that, my sentiment column has the following output below (I did an example table with dummy numbers below).

```
 text   | sentiment score
 ------------------------
 nice   | (0.45, 4.33)
 good   | (0.45, 4.33)
 ok     | (0.45, 4.33)
```

And the output I would like to get is this, where I split the sentiment column into two columns, but add those columns onto the current dataframe.

```
text | polarity | subjectivity
------------------------------
nice |0.45      | 0.433
good |0.45      | 0.433
ok   |0.45      | 0.433
```

Is there a way to do this in Python 2.7?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that produced your example table.

Comment: Whoops. Edited with code to get the sentiment column.

Comment: So I am guessing `test_df` is a `pd.DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want to do with `pandas`:

```
sentiment_series = df['sentiment score'].tolist()

columns = ['polarity', 'subjectivity']

df = pd.DataFrame(sentiment_series, columns=columns, index=df.index)
```

Comment: This erases the other content on the 'df' data frame since it is replacing values in the data frame. is there any way to concat the new columns to the 'df'